# How to debug code running in node with electron package

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have an application using Angular 5, node-adodb and Electron (see package.json below)

When running Angular and Electron in development mode, everything is working fine. When I cal the Electron 'ipcMain.on('select'...) (see below), the SQL 'select' is done to the database, then returns to my Angular application.

When I package everything withing an Electron package, the same SQL 'select' does not return at all. Does not got to 'then' and not to 'catch'.

How can I debug that situation? You have a solution to suggest to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

main.js

```
ipcMain.on('select', (event, type, sql) => {

    const reply = 'reply-select-' + type;

    // Code run until here

    connection = ADODB.open(databasePath);

    // Code run until here

    connection
      .query(sql)
      .then((data) => {

        // Code does not go here

        event.sender.send(reply, { status: 0, message: '', data: data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {

        // Code does not go here

        event.sender.send(reply, { status: 1, message: error.message, data: {} });
      });
  });
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build-electron": "ng build --base-href . && cp src/main.js dist",
    "package-win": "npm run build-electron && electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --version-string.ProductName=\"MyApp\" --out=release-builds"
}
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.0.0",
    "@clr/angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@clr/icons": "^0.11.0",
    "@clr/ui": "^0.11.0",
    "@ngforage/ngforage-ng5": "^1.0.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.0.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.2",
    "ngx-electron": "^1.0.4",
    "node-adodb": "^4.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.5.8",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "electron": "^1.7.10",
    "electron-packager": "^10.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using IPC and the main process to do this? The full features of node are accessible in the renderer process which can be debugged though the dev tools.

The main process should only be used for creating BrowserWindows and for accessing electron APIs which are marked in the docs as only accessible via the main process.

[Check out this article](https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2) for more details of the differences between the main/renderer and what they are used for.